# Rails runs commands twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running my rails 4 application locally, every GET, PUT, etc. appears to run twice.  I've cleaned the assets, thinking that this is causing the issue, but it does not appear to be the case.  Interestingly, even commands run from the console appear to be run twice.  For example, this is the output I get when asking about my users:

```
2.0.0-p247 :005 > User.all
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, ...
```

Any ideas as to what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the User model code?

Answer (score 1):

I think its an open issue in Rails 4,

View this issue on [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11415), thats exactly your case.

try this work around,

```
config.paths["log"] = '/dev/null'
```

Comment: Thanks.  The solution does not actually work for me, but since it appears to be a logger bug, I'm not going to worry about it.